# Error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'name') when using ejs with nodejs

Tags: node.js, ejs

This error occurs when I'm using ejs, otherwise it's working fine with fetch request or postman request. it occurs only with brand data, when I'm using ejs it's making double request in first request it's sending data to client but in second request it's sending null, that is the reason error occurs but don't know why it' sending null and making double requests.

## backend

```
  const brandId = req.params.id;
  const brand = await Brand.findOne({ _id: brandId });
  const vehicles = await Vehicle.find({ brand: brandId });
  console.log(brand);
  res.render("brand", { brand, vehicles });
```

## front end

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <%- include('partials/_head'); %>
    <title>Home</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%- include('partials/_header'); %>
    <div class="container">
      <main>
        <section class="showcase">
          <div class="showcase-brand">
            <div class="brand-title"><%= brand.name %> vehicles</div>
            <div class="brand-logo">
              <img src="<%= brand.image %>" alt="brand-logo" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
        <section class="brand-vehicles">
          <div class="brand-vehicles-list">
            <% vehicles.forEach(vehicle => { %>
            <a href="#" class="brand-vehicle">
              <img
                src="https://s7d1.scene7.com/is/image/hyundai/2023-sonata-hybrid-limited-ultimate-red-019:Vehicle-Carousel?fmt=webp-alpha"
                alt="vehicle-img"
              />
              <p><%= vehicle.name %></p>
            </a>
            <% }) %>
          </div>
        </section>
      </main>
      <%- include('partials/_sidebar'); %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

## console log

```
Server is running on port:3000...
`{
  _id: 'tesla',
  name: 'tesla',
  image: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/bd/Tesla_Motors.svg/800px-Tesla_Motors.svg.png',
  createdAt: 2023-05-23T08:21:27.743Z,
  updatedAt: 2023-05-23T08:21:27.743Z,
  __v: 0
}
null
TypeError: C:\Users\winne\Documents\wikiwheels\views\brand.ejs:13
    11|         <section class="showcase">
    12|           <div class="showcase-brand">
 >> 13|             <div class="brand-title"><%= brand.name %> vehicles</div>
    14|             <div class="brand-logo">
    15|               <img src="<%= brand.image %>" alt="brand-logo" />
    16|             </div>

Cannot read properties of null (reading 'name')
    at eval ("C:\\Users\\winne\\Documents\\wikiwheels\\views\\brand.ejs":18:32)
    at brand (C:\Users\winne\Documents\wikiwheels\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:703:17)
    at tryHandleCache (C:\Users\winne\Documents\wikiwheels\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:274:36)
    at exports.renderFile [as engine] (C:\Users\winne\Documents\wikiwheels\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:491:10)
    at View.render (C:\Users\winne\Documents\wikiwheels\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (C:\Users\winne\Documents\wikiwheels\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:657:10)
    at Function.render (C:\Users\winne\Documents\wikiwheels\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:609:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\winne\Documents\wikiwheels\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1039:7)
    at getBrand (C:\Users\winne\Documents\wikiwheels\controller\brand.js:23:7)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  path: 'C:\\Users\\winne\\Documents\\wikiwheels\\views\\brand.ejs'
}
null
TypeError: C:\Users\winne\Documents\wikiwheels\views\brand.ejs:13
    11|         <section class="showcase">
    12|           <div class="showcase-brand">
 >> 13|             <div class="brand-title"><%= brand.name %> vehicles</div>
    14|             <div class="brand-logo">
    15|               <img src="<%= brand.image %>" alt="brand-logo" />
    16|             </div>

Cannot read properties of null (reading 'name')
    at eval ("C:\\Users\\winne\\Documents\\wikiwheels\\views\\brand.ejs":18:32)
    at brand (C:\Users\winne\Documents\wikiwheels\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:703:17)
    at tryHandleCache (C:\Users\winne\Documents\wikiwheels\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:274:36)
    at exports.renderFile [as engine] (C:\Users\winne\Documents\wikiwheels\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:491:10)
    at View.render (C:\Users\winne\Documents\wikiwheels\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (C:\Users\winne\Documents\wikiwheels\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:657:10)
    at Function.render (C:\Users\winne\Documents\wikiwheels\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:609:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\winne\Documents\wikiwheels\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1039:7)
    at getBrand (C:\Users\winne\Documents\wikiwheels\controller\brand.js:23:7)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  path: 'C:\\Users\\winne\\Documents\\wikiwheels\\views\\brand.ejs'
}`
```

Comment: Why is it making a double request? Did you check the value of `brandId`?

Comment: double checked...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error typically occurs when we call multiple routes at single entry points, if you don't believe then just for testing comment the other routes then the same route will work fine. If you're using restAPI then make sure double check all routes may be somewhere you're calling multiple routes with the same entry point.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).